# Get PID of javaws jnlp applet under linux

Tags: java, linux, jnlp

I'm trying to run a java (jnlp) applet from bash and get the PID of the created process.

Using this command :

```
javaws myapplet.jnlp > /dev/null & echo $!
```

This returns a pid of the first instance of java that loads the jnlp; i guess, but has nothing to do with the final java process running.

Any clues ?

Found out the original javaws as follows :

```
#!/bin/sh
prog="$0"
while [ -h "$prog" ]; do prog=$(readlink -f $prog); done
[ $# -eq 0 ] && set -- -viewer
exec $(dirname $prog)/javaws.real "$@"
```

Is there a way to modify so it gives the PID of the child process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [agent .jar file](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/07/javaagent-option.html) and load that using the -J option of `javaws`.  `-J` arguments are passed directly to the target VM and are combined with the vm args in the .jnlp file, so you can load a local agent library in the same process as the application.

---

Example:

[This agent library](http://www.finnw.me.uk/getpid.zip) contains a `premain` method that stores the current PID (accessed via [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)) in a text file.

Assuming `getpid.jar` and `jna.jar` are in the current directory it can be launched with:

```
javaws -J-javaagent:getpid.jar=pid.txt myapplet.jnlp
```

This will start the applet after writing its PID to the file `pid.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would do the trick, but to find a pid, more generally, I use this alias

```
alias prs='ps faux|grep -v grep|grep "$@"'
```

and then

```
prs my_prog
```

Comment: Mmh not what i was searching for, because i want to get the PID at launch, not afterwards, i also have many instances of this applet running