# how to kill firefox gracefully from command line

Tags: java, firefox, ubuntu, automation

I am writing a program that needs to open a list of URLs. I have firefox on Ubuntu12.04, and every time I kill firefox and reopen it, there will be a message asking if I want to restore the previous sessions or not, which is quite annoying.

I invoke firefox(in Java) using

```
Runtime r= Runtime.getRuntime();
r.exec("firefox -new-instance www.google.com");
```

and kill it using

```
r.exec("killall firefox");
```

Is there a way to kill and reopen firefox more gracefully? I want the program run automatically without any pop-up messages or human intervention. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change the settings of FF. So it would not be so annoying.

Comment: ^thanks @MUG4N, but not quite relevant.

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284139/how-do-i-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-process-started-in-java Actually, this isn't the correct answer but it helps.

Comment: thanks @Vash, I did that, but it happens again. Sometimes it pops up a window says "Firefox closed Unexpectedly While starting" and let me choose if continue in "Safe Mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to load and stop [Firefox](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver).  You can get a separate Firefox instance with a separate profile.  You won't be asked to restore sessions.

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
driver.get(url);
```

Then to close the browser and any child windows:

```
driver.quit();
```

Comment: Thanks mike! exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot kill Firefox gracefully from Java, but you can change your firefox settings so that it wont ask you everytime it re-opens.

See the link [Firefox Restore Options](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Session_Restore) which will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of launching firefox directly, launch a shell script that launches firefox in the background, then prints the PID of the firefox process on the standard out.

Then you can read the PID back through the `Process` object returned by `Runtime.exec()`