# how to kill runtime.exec?

Tags: java, process, exec

I use the code below , in my jframe in order to execute a shell script via java program, but when i implement an other method to stop runing process, this method is blocked by th first and i can't stop my program. So i msut kill the new process, the problem is how to get the pid of the process and how to put it in background, in order to kill it.

```
public static void execShellCmd(String cmd) {
    try {

        testPath = getPath();

        System.out.println(cmd);
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        process = runtime.exec(new String[] { "sh",
                testPath + "/install.sh", cmd, "&" });
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        value = exitValue;
        System.out.println("exit value: " + exitValue);
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("exec response: " + line);
            log = line;
            writeToFile(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5284139/837154

Comment: thank you. i think it is the some problem. but their is no solution proposed

Answer (score 2):

If your "other method" has access to the `Process` object returned by the original `exec` then you can simply call `process.destroy()` to kill the running process. You don't need to know the native PID.  Here's a more-or-less complete example using [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) (there may be a few try/catch blocks I've forgotten):

```
private Process runningProcess = null;

public static void execShellCmd(String cmd) {
    if(runningProcess != null) {
        // print some suitable warning about process already running
        return;
    }
    try {

        testPath = getPath();

        System.out.println(cmd);
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runningProcess = runtime.exec(new String[] { "sh",
                testPath + "/install.sh", cmd });

        new SwingWorker<Integer, Void>() {
            protected Integer doInBackground() {
                // read process output first
                BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("exec response: " + line);
                    log = line;
                    writeToFile(line);
                }

                // only once we've run out of output can we call waitFor
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        return runningProcess.waitFor();
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing, wait again
                    } finally {
                        Thread.interrupted();
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }

            protected void done() {
                runningProcess = null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}

public static void stopProcess() {
    if(runningProcess != null) {
        runningProcess.destroy();
    }
}
```

As long as `execShellCmd` and `stopProcess` are only called from the event dispatch thread then no synchronization is necessary, as all accesses to the `runningProcess` field happen on the same thread (the point of `SwingWorker` is that `doInBackground` happens on a worker thread but `done` is run on the EDT).

Comment: I implemented an other method calling process. destroy but once the method implemented to run the script is running. i can't run an other method. and i have no access.i must wait the end of the execution of the shell script. So my idea is to put the execution in a thread and run it in background and the destroy in other.

Comment: You mention that this is called from a JFrame, so yes, the `waitFor` call should definitely not be done on the event handler thread, it needs to go on a background thread (e.g. using a SwingWorker).

Comment: i have 2 jbutton. one to run and other to stop. when i run the program i can't stop it

Comment: @user2043602 I've added a SwingWorker example, does that help?

Comment: @user2043602 also note that I've _deliberately_ removed the `&` from the end of your `runtime.exec` command line - you don't need to background the process at the shell level because external processes are always asynchronous with respect to java.  I suspect the `&` may have been one of the main causes of your previous problems...

Comment: i made th change that you heva recomended but, i still have the some problem

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can employ the features present in [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

In your existing class containing your UI, you have to add something similar to this:

```
//class variable to store the future of your task
private Future<?> taskFuture = null;

//to be called from button "Start" action handler
public void actionStart() {

  //don't double start, if there is one already running
  if(taskFuture == null || taskFuture.isDone()) {

    //create the new runnable instance, with the proper commands to execute
    MyShellExecutor ex = new MyShellExecutor(new String[] { "sh",testPath + "/install.sh", cmd, "&" });

    //we only need one additional Thread now, but this part can be tailored to fit different needs
    ExecutorService newThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    //start the execution of the task, which will start execution of the shell command
    taskFuture = newThreadExecutor.submit(ex);
  }
}

//to be called from button "Stop" action handler
public void actionStop() {
  //if not already done, or cancelled, cancel it
  if(taskFuture !=null && !taskFuture.isDone()) {
    taskFuture.cancel(true);
  }
}
```

The main component doing the job is the `Runnable` which I named `MyShellExecutor`, and looks like this:

```
public class MyShellExecutor implements Runnable {

    //stores the command to be executed
    private final String[] toExecute;

    public MyShellExecutor(String[] toExecute) {
        this.toExecute=toExecute;
    }

    public void run() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = null;

        try {
            process = runtime.exec(toExecute);

            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("exit value: " + exitValue);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("exec response: " + line);
                //do whatever you need to do
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //thread was interrupted.
            if(process!=null) { process.destroy(); }
            //reset interrupted flag
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //an other error occurred
            if(process!=null) { process.destroy(); }
        }

    }
}
```

Note: when running time consuming operations, be sure not to do it on the UI thread. That just blocks the user, and doesn't provide a nice user experience. Always do anzthing that might make the user wait on a different Thread.

Recommended reading: [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://jcip.net)

Comment: thank you. i was looking at the same problem as the op today and adapted the proposed solution. nice, clean and does what it should do.