# Process ID of new process by processBuilder

Tags: java, exec, processbuilder

How can I get process ID of new process created by ProcessBuilder or exec in JAVA?

Comment: IIRC, that's totally impossible.

Comment: you could start by Googling: [How to get PID of process I've just started within java programm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-programm)

Comment: Sounds Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284139/how-do-i-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-process-started-in-java