# get the process id of a running java application from a windows application

Tags: java, c++, windows, winapi

I am launching a java application (testApp.exe) using **CreateProcess()** win32 API. **PROCESS_INFORMATION** structure is returning me a process id that does not exist in the list of PIDs in taskmanager or **EnumProcesses()** API. I can see there is one **javaw.exe** is launched having some different process id. this javaw.exe process id is different from PID returned by PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.

How can I get the correct PID.

I want to launch this java application, and sometime later I want to kill this java application using PID.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284139/how-do-i-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-process-started-in-java

Answer (score 0):

It should be physically impossible for `CreateProcess()` to report a PID that TaskManager does not see (unless there is a low-level Trojan/rootkit that is hiding the PID).  Until the process ends AND you close the handles that `CreateProcess()` returns, the process exists and its PID cannot disappear.

What is most likely happening is that you close the handles from `CreateProcess()`, and the new process in question is exiting, before you have a chance to look in TaskManager or enumerate the running processes in code.