# ID of a Process from Java Program on Windows 64-bit

Tags: java, windows, process, pid, taskkill

In Java program I've object of `Process`, I want to know it's `PID`. Program is running on Windows 64-bit machine. I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program), but couldn't make them work.

I need `PID` of process, because I want to kill the process if it's still running) after timeout. `Process#destroy` doesn't kill subprocesses.

Comment: I hope you need to browse through 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

This id would help you with sample code as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284139/how-do-i-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-process-started-in-java

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala: First one discusses about **PID of Java program itself, and not process spawned from it**, in second no answer provided particular way for windows 64-bit machine.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yes, it doesn't kill subprocesses of Process. Edited question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah,okay. You will need a JNI/JNA solution, maybe something like [this](http://cnkmym.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/how-to-get-process-id-in-windows.html)