# Ctrl C through OutputStreamWriter in Linux

Tags: java, linux, netbeans-6.9

I have a shell script running through a process runtime on Java.
This Shell Script only stops when you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
Right now I catch the InputStream from the script in a JTextArea.
but I can't send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

When you run <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on a Shell Konsole the script stops and sends back information.
and this information is the one that I Can't Catch.

So
How can I Send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> Through Process runtime?
How can I catch the Inputstream from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

```
File dirw = new File("/home/mydir/sh/");
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = null;
process = runtime.exec("./start_test.sh", null, dirw);

OutputStream outp = new OutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;

int cont = 1;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        jtextarea.append("LineOK " + line + "\n");
         if( cont == 10) {
             outp.write(3);    //sending Ctrl+C
             outp.flush();
             cont =0;
         }
         cont ++;
}
```

Comment: for one you are writing the character '3' not the control code.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is a command sent from user to shell. When shell receives it, it sends SIGINT to the foreground process.

To do this in Java use [Process.sendSignal(pid, Process.SIGNAL_QUIT)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#sendSignal%28int,%20int%29) - this only works on Android.

**Update:** the above command is wrong as it's only available on Android.

The correct way is to send `kill -2 pid`. Beware: this is UNIX-only solution. Another problem is getting the `pid` (process id). It turns out there is no OS-agnostic solution to it: [How to get PID of process I've just started within java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/know-pid-java-process)

The solution is to resort to OS-dependent hacks as mentioned in the link (getting pid from Process via reflection).

Comment: I'm working with Serial Port and Process does not have the method sendSignal

Comment: I try to do it as you suggested but it didn't work. I found the Process Id. but when i want to kill it (typing Kill -SIGINT PID) nothing happend on the konsole frame, i'm still receiving information as if I were still running the program but on the Process table (KsysGuard) it did kill it. I also try differente Signals but i got the same results. As I told you before on Konsole when you hit Ctrl+c the program stops running and sends back information.