# Get process id of Scala.sys.process.Process

Tags: scala

If I started a process using Scala Process/ProcessBuilder. How can I get the pid of the process that was created?

I could not find any mention of the pid in the official docs:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.Process
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scala.sys.io.process` classes are wrappers around the Java classes for starting processes, and unfortunately it is difficult to obtain the PID from this API. See the stackoverlow question for this, [How to get PID of process I've just started within java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program).

Comment: Wow, surprised to know this is not supported. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

2016: same question; I've been clicking through related questions for a few minutes, but still couldn't find any solution that is generally agreed upon. Here is a Scala version inspired by LRBH10's Java code in the answer linked by wingedsubmariner:

```
import scala.sys.process.Process

def pid(p: Process): Long = {
  val procField = p.getClass.getDeclaredField("p")
  procField.synchronized {
    procField.setAccessible(true)
    val proc = procField.get(p)
    try {
      proc match {
        case unixProc 
          if unixProc.getClass.getName == "java.lang.UNIXProcess" => {
          val pidField = unixProc.getClass.getDeclaredField("pid")
          pidField.synchronized {
            pidField.setAccessible(true)
            try {
              pidField.getLong(unixProc)
            } finally {
              pidField.setAccessible(false)
            }
          }
        }
        // If someone wants to add support for Windows processes,
        // this would be the right place to do it:
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(
          "Cannot get PID of a " + proc.getClass.getName)
      }
    } finally {
      procField.setAccessible(false)
    }
  }
}

// little demo
val proc = Process("echo 'blah blah blaaah'").run()
println(pid(proc))
```

WARNING: scala code runner is essentially just a bash script, so when you use it to launch scala programs, it will do thousand things before actually starting the `java` process. Therefore, the PID of the `java`-process that you are actually interested in will be much larger than what the above code snippet returns. So this method is essentially useless if you start your processes with `scala`. Use `java` directly, and explicitly add Scala library to the classpath.

Comment: Tested with Scala 2.12 and Java 8