# How to get a process id of exe running through java program

Tags: java, windows, jna, pid

I am running a exe through java runtime api

```
     Process process = runTime.exec("cmd.exe /c start abc.exe "+Id, null, new       File("D:/My"));
```

and retrieving the process id using jna like this -

```
    Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetProcessId((Long) f.get(process));
```

but the process id return is not of abc.exe but of cmd.exe ..... i need the process id of abc.exe . Do not know how to get that can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cant get the process id of the exe start through cmd.exe but my purpose was served by making the cmd.exe to wait till the child exe is running using following command

```
Process process = runTime.exec("cmd.exe /c start /wait abc.exe "+Id, null, new       File("D:/My"));
```

and i got the process id of the cmd.exe using jna-api

Answer (score 4):

The `process` is an object of type `java.lang.Process`. You can get the process id of `abc.exe` by using the Reflection API.

```
Field field = process.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
field.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println( field.get( process ) );
```

Comment: +1 Note: this will give the process of the `cmd.exe` which is run, but not the process id of any process it runs.

Comment: This will only work under Unix-type OSes. Under Windows there is a "handle" field that you can access using a similar method, but it does not reflect the operating system PID of the launched process; however you can access it using jna as explained there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43426878/170637