# How to find the id of the child process?

Tags: java

Original question : I successfully found the pid of a process using the following code. I'm looking to get the id of the child process, and here I believed I would achieve it by finding the id of the InputStreamReader. I'm not going about this the right way, however, as I'm unable to pinpoint which part of my code would correctly return an id of the child process.

Update and more info : My goal is keep track of the parent process id, announce the creation of a child process with it's ID and the parent's ID. Finally, announce the termination of the child process.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


class processes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/ls");
        final InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        final InputStream was = p.getInputStream();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                InputStreamReader wasr = new InputStreamReader(was);
                int isid = 0;
                int ch;
                if(isr.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.UNIXProcess")) {
                /* get the PID on unix/linux systems */
                try {
                    Field i = isr.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
                    i.setAccessible(true);
                    isid = i.getInt(isr);
                    System.out.println("is process");
                    }
                catch (Throwable e) {
                    }
                }
                try {
                    System.out.println(isid);

                    while ((ch = isr.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.print((char) ch);
                    while ((ch = wasr.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.print((char) ch);

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

        p.waitFor();
        t.join();
        int pid = 0;
        //final int isid = 0;
        //int isid = 0;
        if(p.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.UNIXProcess")) {
            /* get the PID on unix/linux systems */
            try {
                Field f = p.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                //i.setAccessible(true);
                pid = f.getInt(p);
                //isid = i.getInt(is);
                }
            catch (Throwable e) {
                }
            }
        System.out.println("Process p " + pid + " terminates.");
        //System.out.println(pid);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An InputStreamReader is a Java object, not a UNIX process. What are you trying to retrieve here?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm trying to find the id of the child process. I thought this would be the id of the InputStreamReader, but now that you tell me it's a java object, i'm rethinking my question.

Comment: `InputStreamReaders` don't have IDs. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking to get the id of the child process, and here I believed I would achieve it by finding the id of the InputStreamReader.

It won't work.

- An `InputStreamReader` doesn't have an ID.
- Neither does the `InputStream` that it wraps.
- Neither does the `FileDescriptor` that is inside the `InputStream`.

And your code won't work because neither the reader or the stream will ever be an instance of UNIXProcess.

If you need the child processes pid, you have to keep a reference to the `Process` object.

Comment: You could probably do it with native linux api. You could probably check what's the pid of the process owning the file descriptor.

Comment: @Stephen C How would I keep a reference to the Process object?

Comment: Process p = ...; // this is a reference to your process

Comment: @JimN I see what you mean, but how can I reference the thread ID with the process ID? I just updated my question a lot.

Comment: @StephenC I'd like to accept your answer, but I'd like to know more about "if you need the child processes pid, you have to keep a reference to the Process object."

Comment: @user25976 - JimN has already answered that.  It is `p` in your code, though I have no idea why you are running `ls` twice

Comment: @StephenC That's a mistake--I was actually trying to just read it twice. I've now removed process q, and the second time the ls is read is with InputStreamReader wasr