# Getting process ID created by ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process, jvm

I created a `Process` with `ProcessBuilder` class in Java. In `ProcessBuilder`, 
in process builder i opened cmd.exe,in task manager a process is opened with cmd.exe and javw.exe for running java application, i want get process id for cmd exe which was started by java ...

Comment: Why are you running cmd three times?  BTW The process id is only going be the process "cmd" at the start not the others.

Comment: i need  cmd.exe process id form above code..

Comment: The question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program)

Comment: i changed Question please check it once...

Comment: `cmd` is `cmd.exe` which you mention three times.  Only the first process'es PID will be available.

Comment: i am creating process there no issue with that now i want get pid for cmd.exe process .give me  suggestions to get pid for cmd.exe process

Answer (score 0):

The JRE's ProcessBuilder does not provide that functionality, you could try [jnr-process](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-process) instead.