# How to get the pid of a Java subprocess?

Tags: java, subprocess

If we use Runtime.exec to create a new subprocess:

```
Process exec(String command) Executes the specified string command in a separate process.
```

How to get the value of the created process?

Comment: in the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program, you can get : Java 9 class Process has new method long getPid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Java 8 (included), you have to use [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program).

From Java 9 onwards, there is a new [`pid()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#pid()) in the `Process` class.