# How to get PID of java.lang.Process in linux by JAVA

Tags: java, linux, jna

I think out two method to resolve this question but they can't reach the expectation .

1. I use the 'Process' to exec "ps -ef"

   I can through this method to get all lines and I can filter them by my running
   command.But If I have many same command process.This isn't work.
2. I use the JNA to get PID

```
    Field field = null;
    Integer pid = -1;
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.UNIXProcess");
        field = clazz.getDeclaredField("pid");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        pid = (Integer) field.get(process);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This way only can get the PID of running window. It isn't the true PID of process.

what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a new API in Java 9 [`ProcessHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) which should work - assuming you have use Java 9

Comment: You can call ps-ef after executing the java program. So with timestamp you can find out the new process just created. Or you can have param for your java program to make it unique. Or you can use ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName(). It is working fine on linux

Comment: @MadProgrammer That should be an answer.

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program and that's reflection, not JNA, which is very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Java 9

Java 9 introduces a number "nice" changes, one is the inclusion of the native PID of a `Process` - see [`Process#pid`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#pid--) for more details

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        // Yes, I'm a bad developer, but I just want to demonstrate
        // the use of the PID method :/
        new Thread(new Consumer(p.getInputStream())).start();
        System.out.println("PID = " + p.pid());
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit with " + p.exitValue());
    }

    public static class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private InputStream is;

        public Consumer(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int value = -1;
                while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
                    // I'm ignoring it for brevity
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can also obtain a reference to the [`ProcessHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) for the `Process` via the [`Process#toHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#toHandle--) method, which is kind of nice

Comment: When I use Process in linux, It will hava two PID. ex: 11102 11104

Comment: 11102 is sh -c cd /usr/lib/projecthouse/github_project_1/target && java -jar demo-0.0.1-

Comment: 11104 is the real PID (java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod)

Comment: but process.pid() always get the first PID ex: 11102 ，what should i do

Comment: So - don’t use a shell script, execute java directly

Comment: Also, if you take the time to read the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) you would find that `ProcessHandle` provides a `children` method - I'd be looking at that and seeing what it does

Comment: sorry,i can't get your mean.Is it mean i can't use RunTime to exec it?

Comment: What does `Runtime.exec` return?  You don't seem to be taking the time to read the links I keep throwing at you - also the last sentence in the answer even shows you how to get a `ProcessHandle` from a `Process` - this all assume you're using Java 9 of course